# Yeoman installation issues on Windows 7

Tags: yeoman

Why does Yeoman need .NET??

```
C:\windows\system32>npm install -g yo

fullname-native@0.1.1 install C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native
node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fullname-native@0.1.1
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\cli.js
```

So I installed .NET 2.0 and added `vcbuild.exe` to the path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcpackages
```

But now I 'm hitting:

```
npm install -g yo

fullname-native@0.1.1 install C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native
node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
    ..\binding.cc(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory [C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native\build\binding.sln]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\fullname\node_modules\fullname-native
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fullname-native@0.1.1
```

Comment: I agree this is pretty sad.  Especially when you have difficulties installing the Visual C++ component!  It works on mac without visual c++...

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this similar issue myself and thought I would go searching for people asking about it. What you need to do is install Visual Studio 2012 or 2013. Failing that you can install the .NET SDK but I found that I NEEDED Visual studio for it to work.

[.NET SDK here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

I am not an expert but as I understand it there are various modules in some of the generators that use node-gyp which then uses the native c++ compiler to build. This is not present in a standard build of Windows and you need to install the SDK or Visual studio to get them. (This is what I am theorising is the issue btw).

For good measure I would install both Visual Studio 2012 or 13 and the .NET SDK. At this point I found that Visual Studio 2015 was not working for me and I had to un-install and install 2013..

Hope that helps!